# How to evaluate execution time when using scipy.optimize?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, scipy-optimize, scipy-optimize-minimize

I am working on a python script that utilizes the `minimize()` function from `scipy.optimize`.  The script works fine, but it is relatively slow, and I am trying to figure out how to (a) figure out where the time is being spent) so I can (b) speed it up.

My current benchmark for "slow" I have a dataset of entities where each entity contains ~5000 samples (i.e., I need to `minimize()` 5000 times/entity.  I have roughly 2000 entities.  My current run times vary between 35-45 seconds per entity so I am looking at a total run time of 80k seconds (or 22.2 hours).  This would be fine if it was just a one-off, but this is something that requires testing multiple models, etc.  So I need to get run times way down.

The main part of the script is as follows:

```
###Initializing Export Arrays
Vmin1 = np.array([])
Vmin2 = np.array([])
Vmin3 = np.array([])
Vmin4 = np.array([])
Vmin5 = np.array([])
Vmin6 = np.array([])
Vclay = np.array([])
Vker = np.array([])


###Initial Estimate
x0 = np.array([0.5, 0.1, 0.1, 0.0, 0.01, 0.07, 0.2, 0.02,])
bounds = ((0,1), (0,1), (0,1), (0,1), (0,1), (0,1), (0,1), (0,1)) 

C =np.array([[rhob_Vmin1, rhob_Vmin2, rhob_Vmin3, rhob_Vmin4, rhob_Vmin5, rhob_Vmin6, rhob_Vclay, rhob_Vker],
              [nphi_Vmin1, nphi_Vmin2, nphi_Vmin3, nphi_Vmin4, nphi_Vmin5, nphi_Vmin6, nphi_Vclay, nphi_Vker],
              [pe_Vmin1, pe_Vmin2, pe_Vmin3, pe_Vmin4, pe_Vmin5, pe_Vmin6, pe_Vclay, pe_Vker],
              [dt_Vmin1, dt_Vmin2, dt_Vmin3, dt_Vmin4, dt_Vmin5, dt_Vmin6, dt_Vclay, dt_Vker],
              [0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0],
              [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1],
              [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]])


def mineral_inversion(x, L, C):
    L_pred = np.matmul(C, x)
    if not np.isnan(L[0][0]):
        I1 = (np.subtract(L[0][0], L_pred[0])/unc_rhob)**2
    else:
        I1=0
    if not np.isnan(L[0][1]):
        I2 = (np.subtract(L[0][1], L_pred[1])/unc_nphi)**2
    else:
        I2 = 0
    if not np.isnan(L[0][2]):
        I3 = (np.subtract(L[0][2], L_pred[2])/unc_pe)**2
    else:
        I3 = 0
    if not np.isnan(L[0][3]):
        I4 = (np.subtract(L[0][3], L_pred[3])/unc_dt)**2
    else:
        I4 = 0
    if not np.isnan(L[0][4]):
        I5 = (np.subtract(L[0][4], L_pred[4])/unc_vwcl)**2
    else:
        I5 = 0
    if not np.isnan(L[0][5]):
        I6 = (np.subtract(L[0][5], L_pred[5])/unc_vker)**2    
    else:
        I6 = 0
    I7 = ((1-x.sum())/unc_unity)**2

    incoherence = I1+I2+I3+I4+I5+I6+I7
    return incoherence   

from datetime import datetime
t0 = datetime.now()
vpor_init = np.float(0.1)

for dd in range(len(depth)):

    ###Log values used in mineral inversion + unity value
    L = np.array([[rhob[dd], nphi[dd], pe[dd], dt[dd], vwcl[dd], vkero[dd], 1]])

    res = minimize(fun = mineral_inversion, x0 = x0, args = (L, C), bounds=bounds, method='SLSQP')
    Vmin1 = np.append(Vmin1, res.x[0])
    Vmin2 = np.append(Vmin2, res.x[1])
    Vmin3 = np.append(Vmin3, res.x[2])
    Vmin4 = np.append(Vmin4, res.x[3])
    Vmin5 = np.append(Vmin5, res.x[4])
    Vmin6 = np.append(Vmin6, res.x[5])    
    Vclay = np.append(Vclay, res.x[6])
    Vker = np.append(Vker,   res.x[7])

t1 = datetime.now()
time = t1-t0
print('Run Time: ', time)
```

At present I am logging the run time at the `for` loop level.  However, this doesn't tell me much with respect to where my bottleneck might be.  Is it at the level of the `mineral_inversion()` function, is it in the `minimize()` function itself, etc.

Questions:
(1) How can I smartly log the execution time to figure out if speeding this up is even possible?
(2) What would be a fair way to state if this is actually 'slow' or if I am just being unreasonable and it is a lot of samples to iterate over?
(3) Are there any obvious bad practices/speed traps that I have thrown in?

Comment: have you tried 'time' to log execution time?

```import time
since = time.time()
# DO YOUR THING
time_elapsed = time.time() - since
print('\t{:.0f}m {:.0f}s'.format(time_elapsed // 60, time_elapsed % 60))
```

Comment: Yes.  If you look at the code I do almost exactly that at the loop level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> trying to figure out how to (a) figure out where the time is being spent

Use pstats module from the standard library for the function-level profiling, and kernprof for line-level profiling.

In a jupyter notebook, it's %prun and %lprun magics.